Animate hidden content on button click
i have a website where when the user clicks on the "next" button it hides the current page and swtiches to the next, like a guide-installer.
And now i need to fade in the pages, how can i do it?
I managed to hide and show the pages like this:
HTML
<div class="main-container">
      <form id="form1" class="form">
        <button onclick="getStarted()" type="button">Get Started</button>
      </form>
      <form id="form2" class="form">
         Content B
      </form>
      etc
</div>

and then i have the javascript function
function getStarted() {
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "flex";
}

How can i fade in #form2?
I tried using CSS, but unsuccesfully.

Can you try to fade in with opacity? From 0 to 1.

How can i do it? From javascript or css? I just started developing

It is very hard to do. Because with display:none you have taken the elements out of the flow. With opacity it is as visibility:hidden. The elements stay in flow. Perhaps you want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367362/2569323 .

Better this https://dev.to/bmsvieira/vanilla-js-fadein-out-2a6o .
